# Writing a regex in LaTeX

Tags: regex, latex

In a LaTeX report I am making I have to write a regex. There is only one in the whole report, so I don't really want to use packages and so on.

This is the regex I am talking about:

```
^\"((\w|\s)+)\"$
```

I came up with this for LaTeX:

```
\grave{ }\backslash\"'((\backslash w\| \backslash s)+)\backslash \"' \backslash \$
```

This gives me like 10 errors, and I can't really see what is wrong. Okay, it looks pretty bad but all the commands should work.

Thanks in advance,

Harm

Comment: Maybe ask this on the [TeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) in the future.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use

```tex
\verb/^\"((\w|\s)+)\"$/
```

Comment: I think the correct way is \verb|/^\"((\w|\s)+)\"$/|. The expression should come between \verb|....this area....|.

Comment: No. Because there is a | in the regex, you can't use | as the delimiter. In my answer, I use / as the delimiter instead.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the problem is that some of those commands (\backslash, \grave) want to be in math mode, but " doesn't.  Have you tried using \verb to include the regexp verbatim?  I'm not sure if it'll look like you want (it'll be typeset in a tt font), but you could do this with something like:

...

In my project I'm using a regexp `\verb@^\"((\w|\s)+)\"@` to do a thing.

...